# Convert day of the month(char) to date format in R

Tags: r, date

I run the following code in R studio and it worked fine in converting the 'start_dt' to date type and saving the output to a new column named 'date'.

```
all_data_cl$date<-as.Date(all_data_cl$start_dt,format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

I wanted to extract the day of the month from the resulting date and store the output in a new column named 'day',for that I wrote the following code:-

```
all_data_cl$day<-format(all_data_cl$date,"%d")
```

Though the 'all_data_cl$date' was in date format,the 'all_data_cl$day' is coming out to be a char type object rather than a date.

[See Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRH4T.png)

Can someone guide me on how to fix that?

Comment: A day is not a date, to have an object of class `"Date"` you need the month and the year. (And for class `"POSIXt"`, you also need the time.) You can coerce to numeric or to integer but not more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
format(as.Date(df$x,format="%Y-%m-%d"), format = "%d")
```